# Will Safari 7.0 run on OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, safari

I really like the new Safari in OS X 10.9, but otherwise don't like much else and want to downgrade back to 10.6 -- the last time I was happy using my computer.

But, can I take the new Safari with me?

Answer (score 1):

No: Snow Leopard runs Safari 5.1.10 at the newest ([via](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history) and [also](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5275)).

I recommend using Chrome or Firefox if you downgrade back to Snow Leopard. There are messages that [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2599452?hl=en) and [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-no-longer-works-mac-os-x-10-5?esab=a&s=firefox%20osx%20snow%20leopard&r=1&as=s) no longer support Leopard, but both seem to still support Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run the official Apple version of Safari 7.0 (nor 6.0) unfortunately, as [confirmed](https://twitter.com/xeenon/status/403366464914092032) by a WebKit Developer Experience Manager at Apple.

However, you can run the Safari 7+ Webkit version equivalent with [QupZilla](http://www.qupzilla.com/)

It doesn't have all the Apple Safari features, but share many of them, including an updated web inspector for development/testing purpose while remaining in Snow Leopard.

For legacy details, note however than QupZilla is and will be running on QtWebKit (which is a [slightly different port](http://www.paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/) than Apple's when is come to rendering despite sharing the same WebCore) only up to 1.x versions.

"[Qupzilla 2.0 will be using QtWebEngine only](http://blog.qupzilla.com/2014/03/new-bookmarks-and-other-improvements.html#comment-form)". Meaning that QupZilla 2.x will later be essentially Chromium/Blink based.